# One to one vs One to many (syntax differences)

Tags: mysql

What is the syntax difference in MySQL between One to one and One to many?

**One to many** looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
a1 int not null,
a2 int,
PRIMARY KEY (a1)
);

CREATE TABLE B(
b1 int not null,
b2 int,
A_a1 int not null,
PRIMARY KEY (b1, A_a1),
FOREIGN KEY (A_a1) references A (a1)
);
```

What does a **One to one** look like?

Comment: Your example **is** *one to many*, *a1* can be referenced by many *A_a1* :-)

Comment: Then how can I make one to one?

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the relationship from many to one by adding a unique constraint.

EDIT:
I am guessing I received the -1 for my brevity. Sorry for that, I'll elaborate to clarify.

Below you will find the one-to-one relationship DDL. I used a UNIQUE constraint on table B to ensure its one-to-one relationship to its parent table A's primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
a1 int not null,
a2 int,
PRIMARY KEY (a1)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,2),(3,4);


CREATE TABLE B(
b1 int not null,
b2 int,
A_a1 int not null,
PRIMARY KEY (b1),
FOREIGN KEY (A_a1) references A (a1),
UNIQUE (A_a1)
);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,2,1),(2,3,3);
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it helps you out!

Comment: MySQL Workbench created this diagram for your code: http://imgur.com/res01KV . It is a one-to-many relation. I would like the relation to be like this: http://i.imgur.com/BqWs6tz.png (one-to one).

Comment: MySQL Workbench isn't all knowing. I am positive my example will only allow a 1-1 relationship of data. Play with it yourself, you'll see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546a7

Comment: As for your images, why don't you just expand the INDEX part of your EER diagram to see what the KEYs are? If that's what you're after.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1W1rUiA.png

Comment: Why makes your relation one-to-one? The only difference between our codes is that you set A_a1 as unique and I set it as primary key. But isn't a primary key also unique? So, aren't our codes describing the same relation?

Comment: On the contrary, our snippets of DDL are fundamentally different and within that difference lies the answer that makes mine 1-1 and yours 1-m. Your foreign key is not the PK, nor is it per sé unique, it's part of a composite PK but also a non unique key on its own.

Comment: If they are truly 1-1, why have 2 tables?

Comment: @RickJames, Not sure who your comment is for but, my answer is an abstract answer to his question. I could however think of some situations where you'd want 1-1 relationship, e.g. vertical partitioning. (i.e. splitting off a test field to its own table for instance)

Comment: Yes, there are a few valid uses for vertical partitioning.  If it is such a case, I hope Tedd will explain the use case.

Comment: Use-cases could be security reasons or in my case even depending on the type of row, I would like to create additional data into a separate table (1-on-1), or other type of data into yet another separate table with other columns (1-on-1).

Comment: Q: Is PK-PK faster with joining tables vs PK-UNIQUE?